# Какие есть способы создания из List<SomeObject> экземпляра Map без использования коллбэк-функций (fromIterable)?

Tags: flutter, dart

Столкнувшись с задачкой преобразовать список объектов в `Map`, решил ее следующим образом:

```dart
class OrganizationFields {
  late Map<String, OrgField> items = <String, OrgField>{};

  OrganizationFields({ List<OrgField>? fields })
    : this.items = Map.fromIterable([...?fields], key: (itm) => itm.name, value: (itm) => itm);
}
```

Но не нравится то, что тут на каждой внутренней итерации `fromIterable` будет выполняться по два вызова. Это выглядит не очень "красиво", и предполагаю что в Dart возможны более скоростные решения. Тем более что в другом месте проекта предполагается *очень* частое пересоздание практически аналогичных `Map` другой сущности, и хотелось бы научиться это оптимизировать. Входные данные всегда списками, и это нельзя изменить, к сожалению.
Поэтому, вопрос: есть ли способы сделать то же самое (так же создать `Map` из `List`'а объектов с использованием свойства в качестве ключа) более шустрым кодом без использования множества вызовов?

---

[Тот же код в песочнице](https://dartpad.dev/e10a488dfa74fd46e5201db93a6681bd?null_safety=true) (с рандомными элементами).

**p.s.:**
<sub>В проекте использую Flutter+GetX, если вдруг это имеет значение.

Это мой самый первый опыт с дартом (в основном на JS пишу), и если делаю что-то неправильно - буду признателен за критику в комментах.</sub>

Comment: _«Входные данные всегда списками, и это нельзя изменить, к сожалению.»_ - Списки прилетают с сервера, джейсоном. Как резервный вариант я рассматриваю ручное переопределение `fromJson`, но схем данных в апишке слишком много, некоторые сильно ветвистые, и писать десериализаторы вручную - это ад и израиль (сейчас разбор данных выполняется через генерацию кода, пакетом json_serializable).

Comment: В любом случае это будет проход циклом по списку что через Map.fromIterable, что через for... Если вы так хотите заморочиться с оптимизация и красивом кодом, я бы предложил выкинуть GetX из проекта, так как это не красиво (со временем как снежный ком будет) и еще очень плохо по производительности (если что, это один большой синглтон)...

Comment: P.S. `items = { for (var itm in fields) v.name: itm };` но это тоже самое и читать сложнее

Comment: P.S.S. с первым вопросом вас!)

Comment: @MiT, понимаю что прохода по списку избежать конечно нельзя, и он беспокоит меня гораздо меньше чем `2n` вызовов при каждом инстанцировании (вопрос не просто так акцентирован на вызовах). _«выкинуть GetX из проекта, так как это не красиво (со временем как снежный ком будет)»_ - о, вот это весьма интересно и тревожно!)) Насчет производительности предостережение учел, исследую этот вопрос. Но не понял второе: от чего оно будет расти как снежный ком, то есть на что следует смотреть чтобы заметить это?

Comment: @MiT, спасибо за поздравление! :) `items = { for (var itm in fields) v.name: itm };` - похоже, это то что нужно: прекрасный простой процедурный код, ноль вызовов. И я даже не думал что можно `for` прямо в литерал поместить Сейчас попробовал простой синтетический тест, вышло так что способ с `fromIterable` медленнее данного выражения примерно на 20% (соотношение сохраняется при повышении порядка объема данных)... то есть, не сказать что разница ошеломительна, но она явно есть, а избавление от коллбэков хуже точно не сделает. Добавишь ответом, чтобы я мог завтра докинуть награду и принять его?

Comment: _от чего оно будет расти_, буквально от всего, вы в единый синглтон объект пихаете контроллеры, а в них модели. Чем больше ваше приложение, тем больше в нем контроллеров, тем больше в них моделей, которые не очищаются (если это не делать вручную). В общем рекомендую посмотреть внутренности getx и не верить 5К лайкам (большинство из которых поставлены индусами). На самом деле у него много проблем, но из-за рекламных статей на них не обращают внимания...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127035/discussion-between-yar85-and-mit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть альтернатива `Map.fromIterable` без `callback`, это `for`/`for-in`:

```
items = { for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) fields[i].name: fields[i] };
// или
items = { for (var itm in fields) v.name: itm };
```