# метод window.history.back(); возвращает на страницу, как возвращаться именно в то место, с которого был переход

Tags: javascript

метод window.history.back(); возвращает на страницу, как возвращаться именно в то место на странице, с которого был переход.

Comment: Можно попробовать на странице с которой перешли по мере прокрутки добавлять якоря, в теории при переходе назад вернется тот же якорь, нужно пробовать

Comment: Да, проверил с якорями работает: перейдите на стринцу [пример ссылки с якорем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1300401/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-listsomeobject-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%b0-map-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/1300733#1300733) потом с той страницы перейдите на какую-то другую и вызовите `window.history.back()` вас вернят назад на якорь.

Comment: Так же можно попробовать в localstorage записывать значение скроллинга и при загрузке страницы читать и скролить до этого места, но есть в таком методе недочеты